# Cannot Save PFObject after updated ParseFacebookUtilsV4

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I updated the ParseSDK to 1.7.5 and also ParseFacebookUtilsV4 (1.7.5)
Then some our users can not save PFObject like this.

```
PFObject* post  = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"PostData"];
PFUser* user = [PFUser currentUser];
[post setObject:user forKey: @"user"];
...

[post saveInBackgroundWithBlock: ^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
    if ( !success || error != nil ){
        ....
    }
}];
```

It returns with error "user objects cannot allow writes from other users".
The user is using Facebook login and siged up in previous version's Parse SDK
(before Facebook SDK 4.0).

Even if the user deleted the app and re-installed, it's same error.
And it never happens the user signed up after ParseSDK 1.7.5.

To login with Facebook, I'm doing like this

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions: @[ @"public_profile", @"user_friends", @"email" ] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error){
}];
```

When I commented out adding user to PFObject, it succeeded.

Please give me some advice.
Thanks.



NOTE: For the quick fix, I stopped adding user on client, and use CloudCode

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave( "PostData", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var user = request.user;
    var obj = request.object;
    obj.set("user", user);
    response.success();
});
```

it works...